# TypeError: $(...).parent(...).next(...).fadeToggle is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a Django site.This is a script that I have included inside the body

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comment-reply-btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle();
    })
})
```

This is my HTML

```
<blockquote>
         <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
         <footer>by {{ comment.user }} , {{ comment.timestamp | timesince }} ago |
             {% if comment.children.count > 0 %}{{ comment.children.count }} Comment {% endif %}
             {% if comment.children.count > 1 %}s {% endif %} |<a class="comment-reply-btn" href="#"> Reply </a></footer>
         <div class="comment-reply">
          {% for child_comment in comment.children %}
             <blockquote>
                  <p>&mdash; {{ child_comment.content }}</p>
                  <footer>by {{ child_comment.user }} , {{ child_comment.timestamp | timesince }}ago</footer>
                 <br>
             </blockquote>
            {% endfor %}
             <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                 {{ comment_form | crispy }}
                 <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ comment.id }}" >
                 <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-inverse" >
             </form>
         </div>
</blockquote>
```

These are my scripts(I included two just to be sure):

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I am getting this error :

> TypeError: $(...).parent(...).next(...).fadeToggle is not a function

I have no idea whatsoever since I copied the code directly from a video

Comment: have you included jquery library using `<script>` tag?

Comment: At first I had this one:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Then I included the another from google just to be doubly sure.But still no result

Comment: Just include **one** jQuery script. Not two and most certainly not three

Comment: I guest the slim version don't include fadeToggle.

Comment: I had one.But same result.Well,I went back to keeping just one but nothing changed.The tutorial guy wrote the same,"exact" thing and it worked perfectly

Comment: the tutorial dude used the slim version

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal no he didn't

Comment: Well,problem solved.I just kept the google cdn and it worked perfectly fine.Thanks for the help everyone))

Comment: Why do you need **three copies of jQuery**? What were you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @Mango Nothing,I was just drunk and desperate.I didn't know anything.I wanted to take this question down from SO but apparently there doesn't exist a system whereby I can do so.Therefore,.......

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal Hahaha  Good luck buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Slim version excludes ajax, effects, and currently deprecated code.
https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/

> **Slim build**
>
> Finally, we’ve added something new to this release. Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version that excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and currently deprecated code. The size of jQuery is very rarely a load performance concern these days, but the slim build is about 6k gzipped bytes smaller than the regular version – 23.6k vs 30k. These files are also available in the npm package and on the CDN:

I guess, Toggle also comes under effects of Jquery. So you will remove slim file reference and also refer either Jquery or Jquery.min

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Use only one jquery library becausing using two may create conflicts. See below code where I have included jquery 2.1.1 version

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comment-reply-btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle();
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<blockquote>
         <p>comment.content</p>
         <footer>by comment.user , comment.timestamp | timesince <a class="comment-reply-btn" href="#"> Reply </a></footer>
         <div class="comment-reply">

             <blockquote>
                  <p>&mdash;  child_comment.content </p>
                  <footer>by  child_comment.user  , child_comment.timestamp | timesince ago</footer>
                 <br>
             </blockquote>

             <form method="post" action=".">
                 <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value=" comment.id " >
                 <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-inverse" >
             </form>
         </div>

</blockquote>
```

Comment: At least link to a 3.x version of jQuery

Comment: You're right.And the fault was with the slim version.Looks like they don't support a bunch of tags that are supported by "better" versions.Thanks for the help))